# Adding the position of a sub-document in an array as field inside that sub-document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am working on a json object that has the following structure:

#### Initial

```
{overs: [ 
 {over:1,
  deliveries: [{runs:1},{runs:0},{runs:2},{runs:4},{runs:0},{runs:0}]
 },
 {over:2,
  deliveries: [{runs:3},{runs:6},{runs:2},{runs:0},{runs:0},{runs:0}]
 },
 ...]
}
```

---

Inside the deliveries array, I want to add a new field `ballNo` whose value is equal to the position of the sub-document

#### Required

```
{overs: [
 {over:1,
  deliveries: [{ballNo:1, runs:1},{ballNo:2, runs:0},{ballNo:3, runs:2},{ballNo:4, runs:4},{ballNo:5, runs:0},{ballNo:6, runs:0}]
 }, 
 {over:2,
  deliveries: [{ballNo:1, runs:3},{ballNo:2, runs:6},{ballNo:3, runs:2},{ballNo:4, runs:0},{ballNo:5, runs:0},{ballNo:6, runs:0}]
 },
 ...]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it using an aggregation pipeline in the `update`.  You may want to include a filter to select the document(s) you want to modify.
Comments are in the `update` aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      // rewrite "overs"
      "overs": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$overs",
          "as": "over",
          "in": {
            // merge previous content with updated content
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$over",
              {
                // rewrite "deliveries"
                "deliveries": {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": {
                      // array of "deliveries" indexes
                      "$range": [0, {"$size": "$$over.deliveries"}]
                    },
                    "as": "deliveryIdx",
                    "in": {
                      "$mergeObjects": [
                        // keep previous content
                        {"$arrayElemAt": ["$$over.deliveries", "$$deliveryIdx"]},
                        // merge new field and value
                        {"ballNo": {"$add": ["$$deliveryIdx", 1]}}
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7AXE5L5Y7q2).